# How can I associate fields with a constructor if it is not a parameter?

Tags: java, constructor, field

I currently have a constructor:

```
private int num;
private String let;
private Set<Integer> set;

public Constructor(int num, String let, Set<Integer> set) {
  this.number = num;
  this.letter = letter;
  this.setint = set;
}
```

Is there a way to add additional fields inside the constructor without modifying the number of parameters? This is what I'd like to do:

```
private int num;
private String let;
private Set<Integer> set;
private List<String> los;

public Constructor(int num, String let, Set<Integer> set) {
  this.number = num;
  this.letter = letter;
  this.setint = set;
  this.los = los;
}
```

But Eclipse does not like that, saying that my statement does nothing unless I add los as a parameter in the constructor. Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: What is `los` supposed to be? You can't just give it no value (or its own value, in your case).

Comment: what does it mean by this line `this.los = los;`? This line is converted to `this.los = this.los;` where there is no meaning of assigning to itself.

Comment: Sorry it is hard for me to explain, I want the Constructor to also have an associated field which I can also modify. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to initialize the value of an attribute in a constructor, you **must** pass the value into the constructor.  You can have a setter for the attribute so that it can be initialized outside the constructor.

```
public void setLos(List<String> los) {
 this.los = los;
}
```

If the initial value is always the same. you can explicitly set it to that value when you declare the attribute:

```
private List<String> los = new List<String>();
```

or within the constructor:

```
public Constructor(int num, String let, Set<Integer> set) {
  this.number = num;
  this.letter = letter;
  this.setint = set;
  this.los = new List<String>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for my inexperience :)

Comment: Sorry, one quick follow up. Is this still possible for a String? i.e. 

`code`url = new String;

Comment: it is:  private String url = new String();

Comment: ahh. than you again :)